# React UseEffect Array Loop Terminating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to view just 3 array items from an existing larger array. Currently using useState to and initialising the array using the first three items from the larger array, then every second getting the next three. This works until the last item is reached and then nothing is displayed. The if block to revert it back to the first three items never gets touched and I don't understand why.

There are 21 items in the 'parent' array so at some point the final item in both arrays should be equal?

Code below

```
export default function Carosel() {
  let maxIndex = 2;

  const [currentTestimonials, setCurrentTestimonials] = useState([
    testimonials[maxIndex - 2],
    testimonials[maxIndex - 1],
    testimonials[maxIndex],
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (currentTestimonials[-1].localeCompare(currentTestimonials[-1]) == 0){
        console.log("HERE");
        maxIndex = 2;
      } else {
        console.log("ADD THREE");
        maxIndex += 3;
      }
      setCurrentTestimonials([
        testimonials[maxIndex - 2],
        testimonials[maxIndex - 1],
        testimonials[maxIndex]
      ]);
      console.log(currentTestimonials[0]);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  console.log(currentTestimonials);

  return (
    <div className="carosel-container flex">
      {currentTestimonials.map((testimonial) => (
        <div className="testimonial">
          <p>{testimonial}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

currentTestimonials[-1] is a reference to a member of the array with the index of -1, which is undefined. In JavaScript you can instead use the .at() method.

The next issue is that currentTestimonials is always equal to the first three indexes when being evaluated by the if statement. This is because you have a stale closure bug. To tackle this one, you can use useRef(). useEffect() is fired once on component mount, and references the initial state value of

> [testimonials[0],
> testimonials[1],
> testimonials[3]]

and maintains that through each invocation of setInterval. The closure does not get updated. You can update currentTestimonials but cannot read from state as you will reference a stale value.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

export default function SOCarousel({ testimonials }) {
  let maxIndex = 2

  const [currentTestimonials, setCurrentTestimonials] = useState([
    testimonials[maxIndex - 2],
    testimonials[maxIndex - 1],
    testimonials[maxIndex],
  ])

  const currentTestimonialsRef = useRef(currentTestimonials)


  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (
        currentTestimonialsRef.current
          .at(-1)
          .localeCompare(testimonials.at(-1)) === 0
      ) {
        console.log('HERE')
        maxIndex = 2
      } else {
        console.log('ADD THREE')
        maxIndex += 3
      }
      currentTestimonialsRef.current = [
        testimonials[maxIndex - 2],
        testimonials[maxIndex - 1],
        testimonials[maxIndex],
      ]
      
  setCurrentTestimonials(currentTestimonialsRef.current)
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className='carosel-container flex'>
      {currentTestimonials.map((testimonial) => (
        <div className='testimonial'>
          <p>{testimonial}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Instead, it might be simple just to have a check to see if you're exceeding the length of the parent array, and resetting the index to loop again.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Carousel({ testimonials }) {
  let maxIndex = 2

  const [currentTestimonials, setCurrentTestimonials] = useState([
    testimonials[maxIndex - 2],
    testimonials[maxIndex - 1],
    testimonials[maxIndex],
  ])

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('ADD THREE')
      maxIndex += 3
      console.log(maxIndex)
      if (maxIndex > testimonials.length) {
        console.log('reached end of testimonials!')
        maxIndex = 2
      }
      
 setCurrentTestimonials([
    testimonials[maxIndex - 2],
    testimonials[maxIndex - 1],
    testimonials[maxIndex],
  ])
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  console.log(currentTestimonials)

  return (
    <div className='carousel-container flex'>
      {currentTestimonials.map((testimonial) => (
        <div className='testimonial'>
          <p>{testimonial}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```